# QString::toStdString() crashes on std::string destructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, crash

I've been debugging this for 2 hours now, and it boils down to this. If I call `QString::toStdString`

```
QString s = "testtesttesttesttesttest";
const std::string &temp = s.toStdString();
```

the program later crashes on std::string destructor

```
__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL ~basic_string()
    {   // destroy the string
    _Tidy(true); // <---- It crashes on this line.
    }
```

I thought it was memory corruption at first, but this happens even if `main()` contains only those 2 lines. Does anyone know why this happens, and also how can I fix it?

My Qt version is `4.8.1`.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? What happens if instead of a reference you store a copy of the string `string temp = s.toStdString();`?

Comment: Same thing happens with `string temp = s.toStdString();`, it just happens earlier because the destructor of the temporary variable returned by `toStdString()` is called immediately. How do I see the version of Qt I'm using? Where do I look? The project has been set up by other people, I'm don't have experience using Qt with Visual Studio, only with Qt Creator.

Comment: try this: `std::string stdUtf8 = qs.toUtf8().constData();`

Comment: The same thing happened to me! And finally I just called toLocal8Bit instead.

Comment: @Najzero Yes, that works. But I'm not comfortable leaving that bug to lurk, because it's obvious something's wrong in the project's configuration.

Comment: @RedX I found my Qt version - it's `4.8.1`. That's what `qVersion()` returned.

Comment: Ok, so at least you have the lastest Qt version. Did you compile it yourself? Or use the binary from the site? If you compiled it yourself did you enable STL support?

Comment: No, not compiled by myself. It's a binary. It comes with Qt Nokia SDK installer. If it didn't come with STL support, wouldn't it fail at the linker or when loading the DLL instead of at runtime? Besides, it doesn't fail at the function (so no 0 pointer because of missing function).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your Qt DLLs need to be compiled with STL support and exactly the same C-Runtime Library as your code. It looks as though you are using two different CRTs at the same time, which would destroy the objects created on one heap by Qt into the heap used by your program.

Check the DLL Usage with the Dependency Walker!

Comment: I opened both my .exe and QtCored4.dll but I'm not sure what to look for. They have an awful lot of dependencies. How do I know if they're using different CRTs? Different names, or something else?

Comment: Just make sure you compiled Qt with the same compiler that you are using for your application. Also make sure you are not mixing Debug and Release.

Comment: Start your application from DependencyWalker ("Profiling") and see, how many MS-CRTs are loaded. If there is more than one, you have good chances to run into trouble.

Comment: That will spot different dynamic CRTs.

Comment: I checked the loaded DLLs using Process Explorer, and my program is using Debug version of Qt, compiled for VS2008 (and my exe is also compiled with VS2008, so no conflict there). I have only one `msvcp90d.dll` and `msvcp90d.dll` loaded.

Comment: What about the MSVCR (80|90) D.DLL?

Comment: I meant to say `msvcr90d.dll` and `msvcp90d.dll`, sorry. Must have been a copy/paste error.

Comment: I'd recommend to lookup in the debugger, if multiple versions of any msvc runtime lib is loaded. If you start (or attach) to the process using visual studio, open the modules window. It lists all loaded DLLs and executables. If it lists more than one of such DLKs thats probably the reason. DependencyWalker is usefull but nor rely reliable. The real horror us the windows SideBySide manager that decides which Dlls will be used.

Comment: The problem is caused by custom changes in the project, see my edit of the question.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing compiler option `/MTd` to `/MDd`.

Answer (score 3):

Most probable reason could be that your Runtime Library is "Multi-threaded (/MT)" and you need to change it to "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)" (if you are on the release version)

If you are on the debug version change from "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)" to "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)"

If you have an odd compilation of Qt, the solution should be the opposite.

You will find that on "Configuration properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library"

Comment: This helped! I linked the C++ standard library statically, but Qt DLLs linked to the system C++ redistributable DLL, which means the `std::string` in question was being allocated by the redistributable DLL and then deleted by the statically-linked one

Answer (score 0):

I tried tackling the problem a different way. I created a new project from Visual Studio, and the test code didn't crash there. Upon examining the differences between the *.vcproj files with WinMerge, I found that the crash is caused by some custom changes in the project concerning - you guessed it - the runtime libraries. This is the patch created by WinMerge with the minimum differences that cause the crash to be reproduced:

```
112c112
<               RuntimeLibrary="3"
---
>               RuntimeLibrary="1"
126a127,128
>               LinkLibraryDependencies="true"
>               UseLibraryDependencyInputs="false"
127a130,131
>               IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries="false"
>               IgnoreDefaultLibraryNames="msvcrtd.lib"
```