# qt std:string Qstring memory crash

Tags: c++, qt

1.Development environment

1)WIN7 64bit

2)VS2013

3)qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.4.0

4)qt-vs-addin-1.2.4-opensource

PS: vs2013 use multi-thread dll debug(/MDd)

2.The testQT project include 3 files, Form.cpp,testString.h and testString.cpp

1)Form.cpp

```
//......
#include "testString.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //...

    void (QObject::*p)(void) = (void (QObject::*)(void))&Form::updateUI;

    QString sss("aa");
    TestString::Instance()->printClassComFunc(sss, this, p, sss);
}
```

2)testString.h

```
#ifndef TestString_H
#define TestString_H

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include <QString>

class QWidget;
class QObject;

using namespace std;

typedef void (QObject::*NotifySelector1)();

#define notify_selector1(selector) (NotifySelector1)(&selector)

class TestString;

struct NotifyItem1
{
    QObject* observer;
    void (QObject::*selector)();
    string selectorName;
};

class TestString
{
private:
    TestString();
    static TestString* _instance;
    map<string, vector<NotifyItem1>* > notifymap;
public:
    static TestString* Instance();
    virtual ~TestString();
    void printClassComFunc(QString name1, QObject* observer, void(QObject::*func)(), QString name);
};

#endif // TestString_H
```

3)testString.cpp

```
//...

void TestString::printClassComFunc(QString name1, QObject* observer, void(QObject::*func)(), QString name)
{
    printf("printClassComFunc name=%s\n", name.toStdString().c_str());
    return;
}
```

3. My problem

In the function printClassComFunc, the param name1 is "aa", but name is "????" and the memory crash.

when I comment the member function pointer from

```
struct NotifyItem1
{
    QObject* observer;
    void (QObject::*selector)();
    string selectorName;
};
```

to

```
struct NotifyItem1
{
    QObject* observer;
    //void (QObject::*selector)();
    string selectorName;
};
```

The problem not happen, but it is random and I do not think it is the point.

4.My analysis

1) the background of the problem

I tranport my other project from mac(10.9.0) to window win7(64 bit), the std:string memory crash, heap free, i thought maybe it is the different implement of std library, windows use xstring and mac use string, so i replace the std:string to QString , and the problem also exist.

2) I google a lot, some people say maybe you load many different c run time library,
i use dependency walker and find i only use msvcr120d.dll and msvcp120d.dll, the qt build-in qt5cored.dll 's old32.dll use msvcrt.dll, but i do not think this is the key problem.

3)some other people say maybe you allocate memory on you exe application and free it on dll side.
the link is

[QString::toStdString() crashes on std::string destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610994/qstringtostdstring-crashes-on-stdstring-destructor)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813810

I think mostly this is the key point, but i also can not resolve my problem.

So your help is my appreciation.